# Windows 2012 R2 Server Failed Security patches; How to see why failure and re-install?

Tags: windows-update, failed

Installed a long list of Windows Updates on Windows 2012 R2 Server.

Not all but many of the Security updates failed, the reason is very vague, just a Code 80246010 and when I click Get Help for this, useless.

Can't find EventViewer entries for these failures, unless I'm not looking in right place.

Also I don't see a way to try to re-install the failed updates.

Can anyone offer and advice on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates that failed to be installed should be "re-advertised" in Windows Updates. You should be able to run Windows Updates to have it reattempt to install the failed updates.

Answer (score 0):

- Every Windows Update installation attempt (success and failure) is shown in the [History section of the Windows Update control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0wT9.jpg).
- You can find additional information in the [Setup log from Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOLup.jpg).
- And for a very verbose output of what's happening in Windows Update, have a look at the C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log file.

If some updates failed to install and are not automatically re-advertised, it is problably because they have been **superseeded** by a more recent update or by a rollup.
Typically, since Microsoft recently introduced the new servicing model, individual updates will not show up anymore as soon as you install the monthly rollup.